# How to check if Android Lollipop battery saver is on

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop, battery-saver

Android Lollipop introduced a battery saver mode that can be turned on at any time, and turns on by default when the battery is at 15% or lower. This poses a problem for my app, since the battery saver disables animations that provide crucial information. (Just to give context, my app allows users to configure an Android Wear watch face; when they save a new "theme," I animate the theme moving to a button on the action bar so that they know where it was saved to. When animations are disabled by the battery saver, nothing happens when they hit save, which I think would be confusing.)

So, is there a way to programmatically determine whether the battery saver is on? That way I can provide an alternative to the animation(s) such as displaying a Toast.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Take a look at [power manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)

It has a method `isPowerSaveMode()` that will tell you if battery saver is on

Example code:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)
    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
        && powerManager.isPowerSaveMode()) {
    // Animations are disabled in power save mode, so just show a toast instead.
    Toast.makeText(mContext, getString(R.string.toast), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Android lollipop `Battery saver` has their own methods which tells you either `Battery saver` is `On` or `Off` like `isPowerSaveMode()` which returns a `boolean` vlue.